# Restore calendar event without sending notification to attendees using MS Graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I need to restore events from a user calendar through MS Graph API without  notification sent to the attendees. The problem is that when the event is created, it automatically sends an email to all attendees, whether it's old or new event. I want to just create the event without any email send. I also tried to add a ResponseRequested=false and responseStatus=None properties, but it's do nothing.
I'm unable to find any option how to control this. Create Event should include a Boolean to enable an option to 'send notifications to  attendees' if its false then it will not send calendar invite to attendee otherwise send.

Here is an example of the request:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var @event = new Event
{
    Subject = "Let's go for lunch",
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        ContentType = BodyType.Html,
        Content = "Does mid month work for you?"
    },
    Start = new DateTimeTimeZone
    {
        DateTime = "2019-03-15T12:00:00",
        TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    End = new DateTimeTimeZone
    {
        DateTime = "2019-03-15T14:00:00",
        TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    Location = new Location
    {
        DisplayName = "Harry's Bar"
    },
    Attendees = new List<Attendee>()
    {
        new Attendee
        {
            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
            {
                Address = "adelev@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
                Name = "Adele Vance"
            },
            Type = AttendeeType.Required
        }
    }
};

await graphClient.Me.Calendars["AAMkAGViNDU7zAAAAAGtlAAA="].Events
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(@event);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: > tried to add a ResponseRequested=false and responseStatus=None properties, but it's do nothing.
This strikes me as a bug.